# Четкое соответствие

Tags: perl

Опять всё забыл и запутался, помогите плиз!

Значит код:

```
$ip = $ENV{'REMOTE_ADDR'};
open(BANLOG, "ban.dat");
while (my $line = <BANLOG>){
chomp;
    if ($ip == $line) { print "$line  =  $ip<br>"; }
   }
close(BANLOG);
```

В файле ip адреса:

```
1.2.3.4
4.2.3.1
3.2.1.4
```

Мне нужно посмотреть, нету ли в этом файле такого же как `$ENV{'REMOTE_ADDR'}`, который равен 4.2.3.1. Всё работает, но если к 4.2.3.1 в файле приписать в конец еще любую цифру, например 4.2.3.15 - он все равно считает что 4.2.3.15=4.2.3.1!  Пробовал и m/$ip/ и с S_ и eq вместо ==.

Как сделать, что бы он искал четкое соответствие?

Comment: @AIex, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Comment: Убрал точки: ~ s/\.//g; заработало, хм...
Всем спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

```
chomp $line;
```

вместо

```
chomp;
```

Если удалить точки, то 1.2.3 будет равно 1.23 и 12.3, что на самом деле далеко не один и тот же адрес.

Comment: Почему 1.2.3 будет равно 1.23 и 12.3? 
1.2.3 будет равно 123! В ~ s/.//g; модификатор g же стоит.
Сейчас ради интереса закомментарил вынос точек и поставил как советуете chomp $line; - результат начальный: 1.2.3.42 = 1.2.3.4

Comment: Во-первых, если удалить точки из "1.2.3" и "12.3", то они будут эквивалентны, "123", что на самом деле - не верно.

Во-вторых, 

if ( $lval = $rval ) { ... }

всегда будет возвращать единицу, т.к. это присваивание, а не сравнение. Сравнение - это 

if ( $vlal == $rvall ) { ... }


Причем, если сравниваются строки, то надо использовать функцию eq, то есть 

if ( $lval eq $rval ) { ... }

Comment: IP адрес фиксированно состоит из четырех "октетов".
В Вашем примере "12.3" быть не может, иначе после тройки еще точку и какую нибудь цифру нужно плиз. Из темы вроде бы ясно что речь об IP адресах идет ))

Во вторых - это всё понятно, что = - оператор присваивания, а == сравнения и что eq для строк - тоже знаю, тем не менее, я незнаю почему, но работает только вариант со сравнением IP без точек методом  if ($ip == $line)...

Answer (score 1):

**^** (начало) и **$** (конец) укажите в регулярке

Answer (score 1):

```
print int "12.3.4.5"; // 12
print "True" if "12.3.5" eq "12.3.5"; // True
print "False" unless "12.42.6" eq "12.42.6!"; // False
```